# Js Ext locking-editing grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

Can I create locking and editing grid in Js Ext??

Can I combine lock and editing grid?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Yes, its possible, as Tom mentioned below, and provided Sencha Docs link. Please accept the answer unless you have any other doubt :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Have a look at the examples on [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/locking-grid.html).